# How to run bash script on Google Cloud VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I found this auto shutdown script for VM instances on GCP and tried to add that into the VM's metadata.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/tree/master/notebooks/tools/auto-shutdown) to that shutdown script.

The config sets it so that after 20 mins the idle VM will shut down, but it's been a few hours and it never shut down. Are there any more steps I have to do after adding the script to the VM metadata?

The metadata script I added:
[image]

Comment: Did you run the `install.sh`  script to install the required dependencies?

Comment: The shutdown script attempts to detect that the VM is idle. However, depending on what is installed on the VM, the idle detection will fail. For example, Google Cloud Logging and Monitoring (if installed and enabled) will defeat this program's idle strategy. The script that you are using is for a Notebook, which does not have background services running.

Comment: Please follow the instructions in the repo. Shutdown script is run when you click Stop instance, so this option is unrelated of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do not post pictures. Search engines do not process images. Your image is incomplete as well.

Comment: Your script is assigned to a shutdown action. The script will not run until a shutdown even is requested from the Google Cloud API.

Answer (score 1):

Startup scripts are executed while the VM starts. If you execute your "shutdown script" at the boot there will be nothing for it to do. Additionally in order for this to work a proper service has to be created and it will be using this script to detect & shutdown the VM in case it's idling.
So - even if the main script `ashutdown` was executed at boot and there was no idling it did nothing. And since the service wasn't there to run it again your instance will run indefinatelly.

For this to work you need to install everything on the VM in question;

Download all three files to some directory in your vm, for example with curl:

```
curl -LJO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/master/notebooks/tools/auto-shutdown/ashutdown
curl -LJO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/master/notebooks/tools/auto-shutdown/ashutdown.service
curl -LJO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/master/notebooks/tools/auto-shutdown/install.sh
```

Make `install.sh` exacutable: `sudo chmod +x install.sh`

Run it: `sudo ./install.sh`.

This should install & run the `ashutdown` service in your system.

You can check if it's running with `service ashutdown status`.

These instructions are for Debian system so if you're running CentOS or other flavour of Linux they may differ.